# 404 error when trying to call servlet from JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets

I'm trying to call a servlet from a jsp using form action, but when I submit the form, my project is looking for the servlet in the wrong folder.

This is my JSP file:

```
<form name="ListAllDiseases" action="ListAllDiseases" method="post">
  <button type="submit">List diseases</button>
</form>
```

The web.xml mapping is as below:

```
<servlet>
<display-name>ListAllDiseases</display-name>
<servlet-name>ListAllDiseases</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>servlets.ListAllDiseases</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>ListAllDiseases</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/ListAllDiseases</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My folder structure is as below:

[image]

And the error message I get when I click the button is:

[image]

Why is it looking for the servlet inside /View instead of /servlet folder? I have done everything as per the tutorials given online, but don't know why it isn't working. Someone please help,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your form's action is relative (your are in /view/Caller.jsp). Change it to `/ProjectClient/ListAllDiseases` and it should work.

Comment: I did try putting /ListAllDiseases, but then I get the error saying "HTTP Status 404 - /ListAllDiseases"

Comment: I'm sorry, I've forget about the context path (when using absolute URLs). It should be /ProjectClient/ListAllDiseases. But this is annoying to do not forget to add the context path into each absolute URL. You can generate the url by using JSTL's <c:url var="actionUrl" value="/ListAllDiseases"/> (this will store the url into actionUrl page scoped attribute) and use it using EL <form  action="${actionUrl}" ...>

Comment: Thanks Kojotak, it works now. But wouldn't this be calling the Servlet directly instead of going through web.xml?

Comment: No. Your servlet is still mapped to the /ListAllDiseases, but this is context relative URL. The context path, which is ProjectClient in your case, allows multiple web applications to run on single web server and acts like a "prefix" for all absolute URLs. You can set the context path just to /, and than servlet's url will be the same as declared in web.xml.